# How to convert this Java code to kotlin code

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I'm learning spring boot. An error is reported when this Java function is converted to kotlin code. How to rewrite this kotlin function?

**Java code:**

```
private long saveOrderDetails(Order order) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> values =
        objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map.class);
    values.put("placedAt", order.getPlacedAt());
    long orderId =
        orderInserter
            .executeAndReturnKey(values)
            .longValue();
    return orderId;
}
```

**Kotlin code:**

```
private fun saveOrderDetails(order: Order): Long {
        val values = objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map<*, *>::class.java)
        values.put("placedAt", order.placedAt)
        return orderInserter
                .executeAndReturnKey(values)
                .longValue()
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of error in kotlin code]

This is the error I'm getting after automatically converting java to kotlin

Here,

```
objectMapper: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
orderInserter: org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert
```

Please suggest how to resolve these errors.

Comment: Maybe try removing the ```<*, *>``` ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors- post the errors as text

Comment: @Hullburg Removing <*, *> is still not working

Answer (score 1):

What about removing `<*, *>`

```
            val values = objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map<*, *>::class.java)
            val values = objectMapper.convertValue(order, Map::class.java)
```